# Notepad++: Encapsulate text in tags

Tags: html, notepad++

I was wondering if there is an easy way to put entire lumps of text in tags in Notepad++.

For example, say I have the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Is there a way how I can select the text in each line and then press a hotkey or something, and have all the text I just selected encased in a tag (such as a p tag)?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at the [Macro capabilities](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Category:Macro) of Notepad++.

Your Macro would do the following, giving you have selected the Text to put in Tags.

```
CTRL-X
Type: <p>
CTRL-V
Type: </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

For more functionality you can also try the plugin "WebEdit" or the plugin "Zen Coding - Python". 
I use that last one myself, but you'll have to install the "Python Script" plugin too, and install Python on your comp...

Answer (score -1):

if you want to wrap every line in list with "tag"
then select lines, go to Plugins / Emmet / Wrap with abbreviation / Enter abbreviation: tag* / press "OK"